# How do I fire a modal for the next step in my introjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, modal-dialog, intro.js

So IntroJS works off of the `data-intro` and `data-step` attributes.

So for instance my logo looks like this:

```
<h1 id="logo" data-step="1" data-intro="Welcome to MyApp, where you can start creating an album for generations! Let us help you get started.">
```

But for step 3 it is on an element that when pressed, the next step should be on the modal that would appear if the element in Step 3 was pressed.

I have this as my `Step 4` which doesn't work:

```
<div class="popup" id="add-images-step-1" data-step="4" data-intro="GETS TO UPLOADING">
```

Right now, when you reach `Step 3` and press `next`, it gives you an empty white box that is off-screen.

How do I get it to focus on that modal?

Comment: Any chance of you showing your entire HTML file, or better put your example on jsFiddle?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

We can monitor changing of steps in introJs with method `onchange()` ([monitor steps on onchange event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17150318/firing-javascript-function-between-intro-js-steps)). On entering step 4 we should show the modal, and on entering all other steps we should hide it (cause user can use non-linear navigation and e.g. can go from step 4 to step 1). Also we should hide modal on `oncomplete` and `exit` events.

```
startIntroButton.on('click', function() {
    var introJsStarted = introJs().start();
    // hiding modal on 'oncomplete' and 'exit' events
    introJsStarted
    .oncomplete(function() { $('#add-images-popup').hide();
    }).onexit(function(){ $('#add-images-popup').hide();
    }).onchange(function(targetElement) {
        // and show modal on Step 4
        if($(targetElement).attr("data-step") == 4) {
            $('#add-images-popup').show();
        }   
        // don't forget to hide modal on other steps
        if($(targetElement).attr("data-step") != 4) {
            $('#add-images-popup').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

You should place Step 4's `data-` attributes on the part of the modal which is actually for displaying popup window and not for hiding content of the page otherwise introJs would highlight all the window of your browser.

```
  <div id="add-images-popup" class="modal" data-backdrop="static">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content" data-step="4" data-intro="GETS TO UPLOADING">
                <div class="modal-header">...
```

Intro of popup window would look this way:

[image]

[Here is working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ivangrs/e0hawect/)

Comment: Thank you very much. At first glance, this looks like EXACTLY what I am looking for. I will test it and let you know if I have any issues.