# r introjs bsModal

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to highlight elements of my bsModal with the r wrapper for intro.js, however cannot get it to work. I have also tried to include custom js scripts, but my js is terrible.

I have also set up multiple different tests hoping it would snag onto something, however it seem like intro.js cannot find the modal's div or any any of the of the elements inside it.  I am using **rintrojs**

Here are some example of people getting it to **work in javascript**:

- https://github.com/usablica/intro.js/issues/302
- [How do I fire a modal for the next step in my introjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28754912/how-do-i-fire-a-modal-for-the-next-step-in-my-introjs)

But I personally don't know Javascript well enough to integrate a custom solution myself. I've already tried :(

Here's a link to an example I've hosted with the issue:
https://arun-sharma.shinyapps.io/introjs/

Does anyone know how I can get the following dummy example to work?

```
library(rintrojs)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)


intro_df <- data.frame(element = c('#plot_box', '#bttn2', '#box', '#modal'),
                       intro = c('test plot_box', 'test bttn2', 'test box', 'test modal'))

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
    introjsUI(), 
    mainPanel(
        bsModal('modal', '', '', uiOutput('plot_box'), size = 'large'),
        actionButton("bttn", "Start intro")
    )))
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

    output$plot <- renderPlot({
        plot(rnorm(50))
    })

    output$plot_box <- renderUI({
        box(id = 'box',
            actionButton('bttn2', 'dummy'),
            plotOutput('plot'), width = '100%'
        )
    })

    observeEvent(input$bttn,{

        toggleModal(session, 'modal', toggle = 'toggle')
        introjs(session, options = list(steps = intro_df))
    })

})
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately, I think this request could make for some useful features in the `rintrojs` library.  In any case, your problems are two-fold:

1. `introjs` should not fire until the modal is available in the HTML.  The easiest way to do this is to use a button within the modal to fire the tutorial.  If you want it to be automatic, you will need some JavaScript that waits until the Modal is ready before firing.
2. `introjs` wants to grey out the background and highlight the current item in the tutorial.  This means it needs to "interleave" with the modal children.  Because the modal is its own stacking context, `introjs` needs to be fired from within the modal to look at modal children.  If you want to look at the *entire* modal, then it is sufficient to fire `introjs` from the parent.  This functionality does not seem to be in the `rintrojs` package yet, but is in the JavaScript library.

In order to accomplish #1, I added a JavaScript function to fire introjs on Modal load (after a configurable delay for HTML elements to load).  This requires the `shinyjs` package.  Notice the `introJs(modal_id)`, this ensures that the tutorial fires within the modal.  In pure JavaScript, it would be `introJs('#modal')`:

```
 run_introjs_on_modal_up <- function(
      modal_id
      , input_data
      , wait
    ) {
      runjs(
        paste0(
          "$('"
          , modal_id
          , "').on('shown.bs.modal', function(e) {
          setTimeout(function(){
            introJs('", modal_id, "').addSteps("
          , jsonlite::toJSON(input_data, auto_unbox=TRUE)
          , ").start()
          }, ", wait, ")
          })"
        )
      )
    }
```

I also added a simple helper for closing the `introjs` tutorial when navigating away from the modal.

```
introjs_exit <- function(){
  runjs("introJs().exit()")
}
```

There was also a single line of CSS necessary to fix the modal-backdrop from getting over-eager and taking over the DOM:

```
.modal-backdrop { z-index: -10;}
```

And a (large / not minimal) working example with multiple modals.

```
library(rintrojs)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyBS)
library(shinyjs)

intro_df <- data.frame(element = c('#plot_box', '#bttn2', '#box', '#modal'),
                       intro = c('test plot_box', 'test bttn2', 'test box', 'test modal'))

intro_df2 <- data.frame(element = c('#plot_box2'),
                       intro = c('test plot_box'))

    run_introjs_on_modal_up <- function(
      modal_id
      , input_data
      , wait
    ) {
      runjs(
        paste0(
          "$('"
          , modal_id
          , "').on('shown.bs.modal', function(e) {
          setTimeout(function(){
            introJs('", modal_id, "').addSteps("
          , jsonlite::toJSON(input_data, auto_unbox=TRUE)
          , ").start()
          }, ", wait, ")
          })"
        )
      )
    }

    introjs_exit <- function(){
      runjs("introJs().exit()")
    }

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  tags$head(tags$style(".modal-backdrop { z-index: -10;}")),
  introjsUI(), 
  mainPanel(
    bsModal('modal', '', '', uiOutput('plot_box'), size = 'large'),
    bsModal('modalblah', '', '', uiOutput('plot_box2'), size = 'large'),
    actionButton("bttn", "Start intro")
  )))
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    plot(rnorm(50))
  })
  output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
    plot(rnorm(50))
  })

  output$plot_box <- renderUI({
    box(id = 'box',
        actionButton('bttn2', 'dummy'),
        plotOutput('plot'), width = '100%'
    )
  })
  output$plot_box2 <- renderUI({
    box(id = 'box2',
        plotOutput('plot2'), width = '100%'
    )
  })

    run_introjs_on_modal_up("#modal",intro_df, 1000)
    run_introjs_on_modal_up("#modalblah",intro_df2, 1000)

  observeEvent(input$bttn,{

    toggleModal(session, 'modal', toggle = 'toggle')
  })

  observeEvent(input$bttn2, {
    toggleModal(session, 'modal', toggle = 'toggle')
    introjs_exit()

    toggleModal(session, 'modalblah', toggle = 'toggle')
  })

})
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the problem by adding

```
.introjs-fixParent.modal {
  z-index:1050 !important;  
}
```

to my CSS.

Working example:

```
library(rintrojs)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyBS)
library(shinyjs)

intro_df <- data.frame(element = c('#plot_box', '#bttn2_intro', '#box', '#plot', '#shiny-modal'),
                       intro = c('test plot_box', 'test bttn2', 'test box', 'plot', 'test modal'))

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  dashboardPage(dashboardHeader(title = "Test"),
                dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(menuItem("item1", tabName = "item1"))),
                dashboardBody(tabItems(tabItem("item1", actionButton("bttn", "start intro"))))),
  useShinyjs(),
  tags$head(tags$style(".introjs-fixParent.modal {
                          z-index:1050 !important;  
                        }")),
  introjsUI()
  ))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    plot(rnorm(50))
  })

  output$plot_box <- renderUI({
    box(id = 'box',
        div(id = "bttn2_intro", actionButton('bttn2', 'dummy')),
        plotOutput('plot'), width = '100%'
    )
  })

  observeEvent(input$bttn,{
    showModal(modalDialog(uiOutput('plot_box')))
  })

  observeEvent(input$bttn2, {
    introjs(session, options = list(steps = intro_df))
  })

})
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```